# PHP doesn't show any kind of errors

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP server at home for development. It is running:

```
Ubuntu 9.10
Apache 2.2.12
PHP 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1
MySql 5.0.7-dev
```

Currently the settings in the php.ini for displayiong errors are:

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

But I do not see any errors in my php script. Also very strange is that phpinfo() shows me this:

```
display_errors Off
```

I checked the php.ini file, and restarted the apache server many times, but with no luck. Does anybody knows how this is possible?

edit:
When I localy set this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

I do receive errors.

Comment: @user - No, that is a duplicate of this. This question is a year older and includes more details.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Is the `display_errors` parameter listed more than once in your php.ini file?  If its defined more than once, the second instance of it will override the first.

Comment: Tnx again for the clear thinking :)

Comment: +1: I've run into this before and yet didn't think of it.  Whoops.

Comment: +1: In Debian display_errors exist in 2 places in php.ini. One where it is commented out and then further down in the file where it is active. I uncommented the first one, and obviously the second one overwrote it. Didn't even think of it before I read this answer. So, thanks!

Comment: I tried this but my page is still blank, any idea?

Comment: yeah, that worked ! I don't know why, but it was twice in *php.ini*

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu keeps separate copies of the php.ini file for each type of PHP installation.

I'm not familiar with the dotdeb release, but I'd guess it'd be in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Edit:
Since this is apparently not the case, try restarting Apache.  PHP won't pick up changed settings until you do.

Comment: I also checked that. My phpinfo() shows me "Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" That is the php.ini I work in!

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since you updated the configuration?

Comment: Yes. I stopped the server and then restarted it again.

Comment: Is the `display_errors` parameter listed more than once in that file?

Comment: errors might also be turned off in an .htaccess file

Comment: I think it is safe to say that you are my hero :). Really weird, but at the bottom of the file, display_errors was set to off. Tnx very much. You saved me a lot of time

Comment: @thetaiko: You should add that as an answer, so iSenne can give you credit for it.

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu, phpinfo() shows display_errors ON but PHP doesn't show any error. Restarting Apache really solved it.

Answer (score -5):

Enable the following settings as shown below

> display_errors
>
> Default Value: On
>
> Development Value: On
>
> Production Value: Off
>
> error_reporting
>
> Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
>
> Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
>
> Production Value: E_ALL &
>   ~E_DEPRECATED

Restart apache server