# Bitwise operator syntax error in php.ini

Tags: php, syntax, configuration, config, ini

I get the following error when i run `$ php -v` command.

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php.ini on line 113
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2013 20:35:47)
```

The error is coming from the following line : `Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

```
; error_reporting
    Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
    Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such setting `Default Value`, you removed the `;` on that line but that explains the PHP default value and other values.

few lines down you will see:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Settings have this syntax: `ini_setting = value`

Add semicolon `;` to both `Default Value` and `Development Value`

[Check the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: Thanks for this. I edited my php.ini looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050426/php-errors-not-being-displayed-in-the-browser-ubuntu-10-10. It's kind of misleading.