# PHP file not displaying anything?

Tags: php

I have the current code and it only works if I comment out the function. Help?
It doesn't show the title tag or anything. I'm thinking it's some syntax I'm missing, but have not seen it as of yet.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Convert to Roman</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function integerToRoman($integer)
{
 // Convert the integer into an integer (just to make sure)
 $integer = intval($integer);
 $result = '';

 // Create a lookup array that contains all of the Roman numerals.
 $lookup = array('M' => 1000,
 'CM' => 900,
 'D' => 500,
 'CD' => 400,
 'C' => 100,
 'XC' => 90,
 'L' => 50,
 'XL' => 40,
 'X' => 10,
 'IX' => 9,
 'V' => 5,
 'IV' => 4,
 'I' => 1);

 foreach($lookup as $roman => $value){
  // Determine the number of matches
  $matches = intval($integer/$value);

  // Add the same number of characters to the string
  $result .= str_repeat($roman,$matches);

  // Set the integer to be the remainder of the integer and the value
  $integer = $integer % $value;
 }

 // The Roman numeral should be built, return it
 return $result;
}
echo integerToRoman(5);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: error_reporting( E_ALL );

Comment: Tried that. Does that just go right under the <?php ? Because that's where I put it.

Comment: its working fine... see demo here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76731f27d4abf3eebe614f156699d127b3b719ff

Comment: What is the extension of your file??

Comment: For some reason it will not show up in my browser.. Any hints? I have LAMP running and have checked all of the php prerequisites.

Comment: did u check the demo?? its even working in my local...

Comment: Yeah, the demo is definitely working. I guess I'll just restart the debian server.

Comment: do it and check if it's working fine.

Comment: its working fine... see on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4bnj-hkdw)

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you should change the following variables in your php.ini:

```
; display_errors
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT 
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

; html_errors 
; Default Value: On 
; Development Value: On 
; Production value: Off

; log_errors
; Default Value: On 
; Development Value: On 
; Production Value: On
```

Search for them as they are already defined and put your desired value. Then restart your apache2 server and everything will work fine. Good luck!

[PHP errors NOT being displayed in the browser [Ubuntu 10.10]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5050426/4725592)

Also check if PHP is installed or not
Try

```
$ which php
```