# Errors won't show up?

Tags: php, html, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP doesn’t show any kind of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648533/php-doesnt-show-any-kind-of-errors)

I don't know why but when i test this code:

```
<html>
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

I don't get any errors like "headers already sent" which i should.
Any ideas why the error won't show up?

I'm using Apache on Windows 7
I have "error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT" & "display_errors = On"

Comment: (1) does `phpinfo();` think it's on? (2) you may have automatic output buffering on, in which case this won't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Output buffering could be turned on automatically. In that case, an error won't be reported to you in your case. Check using **[`ob_get_level`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php)**

```
<?php
    echo ob_get_level() //at the beginning of your script.
    ...
    ...
?>
```

If the `php.ini` directive **output_buffering** is turned on, you'll get 1 as the return value.

Comment: Ok thx, i've turned off output_buffering & it works now:-)

Comment: Now i have a question about such a code:

Comment: <?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
echo 'Hello';

I'm wondering what would be the result of the code. I know - the browser gets header & redirects to 'http://www.example.com/'. But what about the output after the 'header' function? Where the string 'Hello' will be sent? If the broser will receive it?

Comment: @Mulligan I answered this on your other question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325398/output-after-header-function. Yes it is received, by the browser, (you can sniff outbound requests using fiddler and check)

Comment: Yes, sorry ut, I still don't fully understand. How would the script behave afeter execution of header function? If the 'echo' statment will be executed?

Comment: Yes. it will be executed, and sent along with a header containing the redirect code 302. But the browser will disregard the content.