# Output after 'header' function

Tags: php, html, apache

I have the code like this:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
echo 'Hello';
```

And i'm wondering what would be the result of the code. I know - the browser gets header & redirects to 'http://www.example.com/'.
But what about the output after the 'header' function? Where the string 'Hello' will be sent?
If the broser will receive it?

Answer (score 3):

**[`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** is used to send a raw HTTP header

It will send out the redirect in its header (different HTTP code, **REDIRECT 302**), along with the content `'Hello'`.

The response headers are processed first by the web-browser before moving on to any content.
Hence, the content of such an HTTP response will not be read or processed by the browser.

**More: [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)**

Comment: While the response body won't be read or processed by the browser, it _is_ still sent, which takes up unnecessary bandwidth and could be a security risk (imagine a redirect for unauthorized users on an admin page with sensitive content).  Always `exit` immediately after a redirect like this.

Comment: To add to drrcknlsn's remark: it is entirely up to the user-agent to choose whether to allow or disallow redirects.. I can just disable redirects for your page in Opera and see the whole thing. `exit`'s, with probably a fallback-link, are key.