# how to display php error message on web page in firefox?

Tags: php, error-handling

Here is my simple codes file  in /var/www/read.php :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
<?php
    echo hello"
?>
```

I ran across the error reporting  when to run `php /var/www/read.php ' on debian console.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/read.php on line 3
```

But there is no error reporting in web page when to  input `127.0.0.1/read.php` in firefox.

I have set the values in php.ini as following:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE    
display_errors = On
```

It is no use for me to restart apache2 with command :

```
service apache2 restart
```

Here is my phpinfo message.
It is no use to add two lines in my read.php file,no error message reported in my firefox.How can i fix it?My system is debian7+php .

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo hello"
?> 

find  /  -name  'php.ini'
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

The problem solved according to 
[PHP doesn't show any kind of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648533/php-doesnt-show-any-kind-of-errors/2648859#2648859)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like those php configuration options are not active. Either you have not restarted your php environment (usually the http server) after changing them, or the php engine uses another configuration file than the one you modified. You can check that using phps `phpinfo()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: can you post the path of the php.ini file that you are edited?

Comment: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  and 
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: you was modified /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or /etc/php5/cli/php.ini ?

Comment: did you even try googling this? see the answer here with 9 upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083533/how-to-have-php-display-errors-ive-added-ini-set-and-error-reporting-but-jus your error reporting will never get called because the script is not executed due to the parse error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `error_reporting()` function should be moved inside the `<?php ?>` tags.

There are usually two php.ini files in a typical setup (One used by the webserver, other one used by the command line).

On a unix distribution, it is usually located somewhere below the `/etc/php` folder, like that for example `/etc/php/apache2/php.ini`.

To be sure what configuration file is loaded for PHP by the webserver, do a simple `phpinfo();` in a webpage and just search for `configuration file`.

If you modify the one used by your websever, make sure to restart Apache afterwards, so it loads the new configuration.

If you want to enforce programmatically setting, you can use the `ini_set` function.

In your case, if you want to see any error on the page.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

foobar();
```

Update :

Adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  won't do anything if there is a syntax error in the page, because the syntax error is thrown before the execution of the script. Try to create another type of error, e.g. call an unknown function instead, and you should see it.

Comment: it is no use for me to add the two lines in my php file,error reporting still not to display on my firefox web page.

Answer (score 2):

Use `error_reporting(1);` or `error_reporting(TRUE);` and make sure no where you have disabled anything pertaining to error reporting

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your php file

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//To show errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//To hide error 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

You also set this is in a common php file or in working file..

Answer (score 0):

You should see which php.ini is read by Apache. It is common for console to use a different php.ini than Apache.

You can `phpinfo()` and see which configuration file is being read by Apache.

However, at the beginning of the `read.php` file add the following line:

```
init_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: it is no use for me to add init_set("display_errors", 1);  into my read.php .

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a nasty habit of giving the white screen of mystery when the error is syntax related. To get around this you can use the include function:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include "/var/www/read.php";
?>
```

Now the syntax error is no longer in the first page and PHP can "compile" it will give you an error message about the broken page.

There are a couple of issues with the first code sample which should look like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "hello";
?>
```

First error reporting directives like all PHP code needs to be inside the PHP code tags. This should result in the code simply ending up on the page in Firefox which is not what you want.

Second echo acts on a string which should start and end with a quote mark. This is a syntax error and at the heart of the no error message problem.

Third all line must end with a semi colon (with the exception of a few block level commands). If in doubt... This is actually not your problem and you code will run without it as long as the code section terminates with a `?>` as PHP will assume `;` for you. However get intot he habit of putting you `;` in place every time and you will not be tripped up by it later.

Now assuming that you are not on a host running in safe mode then you can turn on error reporting at the ini level in your code too

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "hello world";
    unknownfunction() // this will throw errors
?>
```

Judging by the fact that you have full control of the system I would say that you should know if you put safemode on. Also I see that you tried the above ini directive to no available (this is due to the syntax issue that I explained at the start of the answer).

Here is some further reading that might be of interest:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_error.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)